# Which design pattern to use when we have classes that does similar high level functionality but the returns different types in methods?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I have an existing C# console application that takes arguments and based on the arguments 
creates an instance of markets (UK, US, MX..) using dependency injection.

Each market class does a 'string GetData()', 'string  ProcessData()' and 'bool ExportData()'.

The application was initially created for one eCommerce vendor's markets. Now I am told to modify it for a different vendor that does a different process. The high-level flow remains the same.

1. 'GetData' to fetch records from DB,
2. 'ProcessData' for any transformation or the likes
3. 'ExportData'.

The difference is Getdata() pulls records from DB and maps to an object. I am planning to use Petapoco. 'ProcessData' might return a similar class. 'Exportdata' currently does an API call but for the new vendor, I have to write to a file.

I was reading up on patterns I am totally confused. At first, I thought I needed abstract factory pattern and now I think the factory method is what I should be using but I am not sure if I am doing it right. Need some guidance/review here. A sample cs file I created from my understanding of factory pattern. This code is based on the headfirst code samples.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using StatusExport.Models;

namespace factorymethod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientFactory factory = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter client code:");
            string clientCode= Console.ReadLine();
            switch (clientCode.ToLower())
            {
                case "costco":
                    factory = new CostcoFactory("accountname", "taskname");
                    break;
                    //NEw vendor might be added
                    //case "walmart"
                    //factory = new WalmartFactory("taskname", "type");
                    //break
                default:
                    break;
            }

            bool status = factory.ProcessData();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    abstract class Client
    {
        public abstract string AccountName { get; }
        public abstract string Task { get; set; }
        //More properties might be added. Some may not even be used by some of the new vendors. For example, Costco Might need accountname and task. Tomorrow if walmart comes, they might not need these two or may need task and a new property 'type'
        public abstract List<T> GetData<T>();
        public abstract List<T> ProcessData<T>();
        public abstract bool ExportData();
    }


    class CostcoClient : Client
    {
        public override string AccountName { get; }
        public override string Task { get; set; }

        public CostcoClient(string accountName, string task)
        {
            AccountName = accountName;
            Task = task;
        }

        public override List<DBRecord> GetData<DBRecord>() //DBRecord class is specific to Costco. 
        {
            List<DBRecord> dbresult = new List<DBRecord>();
            //dbresult = db return data mapped to an object DBRecord using petapoco. Another vendor might have a different class to which DB records are mapped. So the return type can be generic
            return asn;
        }

        public override List<T> ProcessData<T>()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException(); //Any data transformation or business logic. Return type might be DBRecord or a new class altogether
        }

        public override bool ExportData()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();//Call API or write data to file and if success send true else false
        }
    }

    abstract class ClientFactory
    {
        public abstract bool ProcessData();
    }


    class CostcoFactory : ClientFactory
    {
        public string AccountName { get; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public CostcoFactory(string accountname, string task)
        {
            AccountName = accountname;
            Task = task;
        }

        public override bool ProcessData()
        {
            CostcoClient gc = new CostcoClient(AccountName, Task);
            var result = gc.GetData<DBRecord>();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think this is the right design approach?

I also want to keep the console project independent of vendor project. So maybe 'StatusExport.Program' for the console application. DLL projects StatusExport.Common to hold the interface and abstract classes' and 'StatusExport.Client(ex:StatusExport.Costco)' for each vendor stuff.

Comment: Looking at the code console app wise it seems that all you need a `abstract Client` class  with one method defined `bool ExportData()`. As for factory - in such  implementation you don't need it becase your `case` statement is your "factory".

Answer (score 1):

You can create BaseClient class that will contains a basic group of properties, and if you need to add something new - just inherit it. You did right, but i think it's better to change **public** modifier to **protected** in your properties **AccountName** and **Task**, to give access to them only from child classes. 
Actually, you can create a BaseClientModels (request/response) for each method if you are not sure that returning type List will be always actual.
Example:

```
public abstract class BaseClient
{
    #region Properties : Protected

    protected abstract string AccountName { get; }

    protected abstract string Task { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods : Public

    public abstract BaseGetDataResponseModel GetData(BaseGetDataRequestModel model);

    public abstract BaseProcessDataResponseModel ProcessData(BaseProcessDataRequestModel model);

    public abstract BaseExportDataResponseModel ExportData(BaseExportDataRequestModel model);

    #endregion
}

public class BaseGetDataResponseModel { }

public class BaseGetDataRequestModel { }

public class BaseProcessDataResponseModel { }

public class BaseProcessDataRequestModel { }

public class BaseExportDataResponseModel { }

public class BaseExportDataRequestModel { }
```

Then let's look on your class **CostcoClient** and how it can looks like:

```
public class CostcoClient : BaseClient
{
    #region Properties : Protected

    protected override string AccountName { get; }

    protected override string Task { get; set; }

    protected virtual IDataReader<BaseGetDataRequestModel, BaseGetDataResponseModel> DataReader { get; }

    protected virtual IDataProcessor<CostcoClientProcessDataRequestModel, CostcoClientProcessDataResponseModel> DataProcessor { get; }

    protected virtual IExportDataHandler<CostcoClientExportDataRequestModel, CostcoClientExportDataResponseModel> ExportDataHandler { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public CostcoClient(string accountName, string task)
    {
//set DataReader, DataProcessor, ExportDataHandler
        AccountName = accountName;
        Task = task;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods : Public

    public override BaseGetDataResponseModel GetData(BaseGetDataRequestModel model)
    {
        if (model is CostcoClientGetDataRequestModel clientGetDataRequestModel)
        {
            return DataReader.ReadData(clientGetDataRequestModel);
        }
        return null; //wrong type has passed
    }

    public override BaseProcessDataResponseModel ProcessData(BaseProcessDataRequestModel model)
    {
        if (model is CostcoClientProcessDataRequestModel clientProcessDataRequestModel)
        {
            return DataProcessor.ProcessData(clientProcessDataRequestModel);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override BaseExportDataResponseModel ExportData(BaseExportDataRequestModel model)
    {
        if (model is CostcoClientExportDataRequestModel clientExportDataRequestModel)
        {
            return ExportDataHandler.Handle(clientExportDataRequestModel);
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}


public class CostcoClientGetDataRequestModel : BaseGetDataRequestModel { }

public class CostcoClientGetDataResponseModel : BaseGetDataResponseModel { }

public class CostcoClientProcessDataRequestModel : BaseProcessDataRequestModel { }

public class CostcoClientProcessDataResponseModel : BaseProcessDataResponseModel { }

public class CostcoClientExportDataRequestModel : BaseExportDataRequestModel { }

public class CostcoClientExportDataResponseModel : BaseExportDataResponseModel { }

public interface IDataReader<TIn, TOut>
{
    public TOut ReadData(TIn model);
}

public interface IDataProcessor<TIn, TOut>
{
    public TOut ProcessData(TIn model);
}

public interface IExportDataHandler<TIn, TOut>
{
    public TOut Handle(TIn model);
}

public class CostcoClientDataReader : IDataReader<CostcoClientGetDataRequestModel, CostcoClientGetDataResponseModel>
{
    public CostcoClientGetDataResponseModel ReadData(CostcoClientGetDataRequestModel model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

    //and so on
```

You have to implement **IDataReader**, **IDataProcessor**, **IExportDataHandler**, make your logic and call it from **GetData**, **ProcessData**, **ExportData** methods, as an example, and get instances via dependency injection.

Then, we can change your factory to this:

```
public interface IClientFactory
{
    BaseClient GetClientService(ClientServicesEnum value);
}


public class BaseClientFactory : IClientFactory
{
    #region Propertied : Protected

    protected virtual IEnumerable<BaseClient> Services { get; }

    protected string AccountName { get; }

    protected string Task { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public BaseClientFactory(IEnumerable<BaseClient> services, string accountname, string task)
    {
        Services = services;
        AccountName = accountname;
        Task = task;
    }

    #endregion

    public BaseClient GetClientService(ClientServicesEnum value)
        => Services.First(x => x.GetType().Equals(GetClientServiceByCode()[value]));

    private Dictionary<ClientServicesEnum, Type> GetClientServiceByCode()
        => new Dictionary<ClientServicesEnum, Type>()
        {
            { ClientServicesEnum.CostcoClient, typeof(CostcoClient) }
        };

}

public enum ClientServicesEnum
{
    CostcoClient = 1,
    Another2 = 2,
    Another3 = 3
}
```

Where

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<BaseClient> Services { get; }
```

you can get via DI too, and then get correct ServiceHandler by enum.

And your main function to call all this:

```
        switch (clientCode)
        {
            case 1:
                baseClient = ClientFactory.GetClientService(ClientServicesEnum.CostcoClient);
                break;
            case 2:
                baseClient = ClientFactory.GetClientService(ClientServicesEnum.Another2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        bool status = baseClient.ProcessData(null); //your model
```

The main thing is - you can use more than one pattern, for example one from Creational patterns, and one from Structural.
If i need some help in code architecture i use this:
https://refactoring.guru/

I think, using this example you can remove properties **AccountName** and **Task**, because of request models in methods.